# is it possible to Send e-mail without e-mail server?

Tags: java, email

JavaMail sends e-mails using an e-mail server, typically through the `SMTP` interface of an e-mail provider. Is it necessary to use an e-mail server to send e-mails?

I have a web site that will send e-mails and if possible I'd like to send the e-mails directly from the web site code without using an e-mail server. The JavaMail FAQ says that an e-mail server is required.

Is there a way to send e-mails without using an e-mail server, either with JavaMail or another `API`?

Comment: `The JavaMail FAQ says that an e-mail server is required.`... you have the correct answer.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can deliver an email directly to one of the `SMTP` servers mentioned in the `MX` record of the address's domain. Usually that is a bad idea,though:

Delivering the mail to a local server is fast - you can almost immediately continue and do something else and let the server handle the delivery.

The actual delivery can take some time, for instance the remote mail server might be slow. Or it might reject the mail first - it is a known strategy against spam to tell a sender to try sending a mail a second time, which some spam bots won't do.

Also the mail server can easily try again a day later or so when the remote server is down, this reduces risk of lost mail.

i found using google `SMTP` as easy way to send mail.

Comment: It would have been good form if you had at least linked to the answer you copied word for word... http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/229273/132835

Comment: What a bad habit to just copy the answer omg.

Answer (score 3):

You need an e-mail server. When you send an email from your address to another address. you are really sending it to a mail server.  The protocol used to send to the server is (usually) SMTP.